# Dynamic Desired Capabilities in Appium

Tags: android, testing, mobile, automation, appium

We have a lot of real mobile devices to execute functional tests on them. We are facing a lot of difficulties when switching devices. I am looking for a dynamic way of changing Device Capabilities programmatically (Android devices) . Could you help me to figure out this? Any link clue may help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want your desired capabilities to change every time you connect a new mobile device to your development environment. may be this library can help you. It also support iOS.

https://github.com/Testinium/MobileDeviceInfo